# Encryption with PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 in java

Tags: java, encryption

I use PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 in java for encryption and my question is about the algorithm internals.
I understand the roles of PBE, Hmac, and aes in encryption process.
My question is: does the Hmac digest the plaintext and then gets appended to the plaintext and get encrypted by aes (as in SSL)? because the result is always a multiple of aes 16 bytes (if i encrypt only 1 character i get 16 bytes as the final result) but Hmac is 32 bytes.
When i read about Hmac i found that the most used way is to digest the ciphertext and append the result to the ciphertext and save it, but it seems not the case in PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128.

I am asking this because i don't want to save the password and rely on Hmac's result to check for password's validity, and also to understand better the algorithm.
(I sometimes calculate Hmac separately again by using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 with different salt and count for secret key generation and append the result to the final ciphertext for more security.)

Comment: There are two parts in the algorithm - "PBEWithHmacSHA256" And "AES_128", which means they operate "independent". In the first step a provided passphrase (or password) runs through a key derivation method that internally uses Hmac256 as hash algorithm. In the end the output is a 16 bytes (128 bit) long key, that is then used for encryption with the AES algorithm in CBC mode. As AES has a blocksize of 16 bytes the output has to be a multiple of 16 (when using CBC mode, some modes show a different behaviour). So the Hmac is NOT appended to the ciphertext (as e.g. the GCM mode does).

Comment: To be honest, I don't like the PBE constructions in Java. These are not algorithms, they are badly specified protocols consisting of many algorithms. It's not a wonder that people get confused by them. It would be much better to keep the PBKDF part and the encryption part separate.

Comment: Fehr: oh i get it now, so Hmac is used for producing a secret key not for ciphertext integrity check. Such naming really confuse the users.

Comment: Bodewes: You are right, and also some algorithms that you find in oracle documentation are not present in provided jdk, and the naming of algorithms is very confusing, also the library and the classes themselves are confusing. Now i do the encryption by using PBEWithHmacSHA256 (very lazy to change the code) and PKDF for message digest for integrity check.